# What to gitignore with shards packages and crystal

Tags: git, crystal-lang

What do I ignore inside of a .gitignore file with Crystal shards? I'm coming from a Node.js background where I would ignore the infamous node_modules. I recently ran `shards install` and got a few new files and directories. For now, I'm ignoring lib/ and .shards/ and saving shard.lock to VCS.

Are there any conventions around this I should know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a first clue with [`www.gitignore.io/api/crystal`](https://www.gitignore.io/api/crystal)

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/crystal

### Crystal ###
/docs/
/lib/
/bin/
/.shards/

# Libraries don't need dependency lock
# Dependencies will be locked in application that uses them
#/shard.lock


# End of https://www.gitignore.io/api/crystal
```

[Johannes Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7401689/johannes-m%C3%BCller) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248147/what-to-gitignore-with-shards-packages-and-crystal/49249094#comment85508897_49249094):

> Tip: `crystal init` sets up a project structure for you, including a `.gitignore` file and other useful defaults.

Comment: Awesome. I didn’t know gitignore.io was a thing. Thanks.

Comment: Tip: `crystal init` sets up a project structure for you, including a .gitignore file and other useful defaults.

Comment: @JohannesMüller Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.